# Does Python guarantee the traversal order of a list iterator?

Tags: python, list, iterator, listiterator

As far as I can see in Python 2.7, the iterator of a list traverse the list in an increasing-index order. I would like to know if this order is guaranteed by Python 2/3, or is this order clearly defined as the behavior of a list iterator.

In other words, if I want to traverse the list in an increasing-index order (and I require it to be in such order), and simply use the iterator for that purpose, is it possible that in some later version of Python the behavior be changed?

Comment: @KronoS So your answer is, it does **NOT** guarantee the order of iterator traversal on a list, right?

Comment: The answer is yes. It would be insane for them to change something like that, considering how it is implemented in source. Dictionaries are a different matter though. Why would they ever change it?

Comment: If that ever changed it would break thousands, if not millions, of python programs.

Answer (score -1):

Iterating order is guaranteed for lists, but not for dictionaries or sets. This holds for both python 2 and 3, and is VERY unlikely to be ever changed.